# DuckDB - Unable to load httpfs extension (after installing the extension from downloaded file)

Tags: python, duckdb

I need to manually install the "httpfs" extension on my office laptop (due to restrictions). For this I downloaded the "httpfs" extension from https://extensions.duckdb.org/v0.9.2/windows_amd64/httpfs.duckdb_extension.gz and copied it to may local path. Then using Python client, I ran the commands shown below

```
import duckdb
duckdb.__version__ 
### '0.9.2'

duckdb.install_extension('./httpfs.duckdb_extension.gz')

duckdb.load_extension('httpfs')
### Traceback (most recent call last):
### File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
### duckdb.duckdb.IOException: IO Error: Extension 
### "C:\Users\xxxx\.duckdb\extensions\v0.9.2\windows_amd64\httpfs.duckdb_extension" could not be loaded because its signature is either missing or invalid and unsigned extensions are disabled by configuration (allow_unsigned_extensions)
```

As per documentation: https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/working_with_extensions.html, I tried loading the extension from the installed path but the error message remained the same

```
duckdb.load_extension('C:/Users/xxxx/.duckdb/extensions/v0.9.2/windows_amd64/httpfs.duckdb_extension')
### Traceback (most recent call last):
### File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
### duckdb.duckdb.IOException: IO Error: Extension 
### "C:\Users\xxxx\.duckdb\extensions\v0.9.2\windows_amd64\httpfs.duckdb_extension" could not be loaded because its signature is either missing or invalid and unsigned extensions are disabled by configuration (allow_unsigned_extensions)
```

Then I also tried with config={"allow_unsigned_extensions": "true"} https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview#loading-and-installing-extensions, but this time with a different error message

```
con = duckdb.connect(config={"allow_unsigned_extensions": "true"})

con.load_extension('C:/Users/xxxx/.duckdb/extensions/v0.9.2/windows_amd64/httpfs.duckdb_extension')
### Traceback (most recent call last):
### File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
### duckdb.duckdb.IOException: IO Error: Extension 
### "C:\Users\xxxx\.duckdb\extensions\v0.9.2\windows_amd64\httpfs.duckdb_extension" could not be loaded: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Is there something that I am missing or performing incorrectly? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DuckDB extensions are served compressed using the gzip format, you need to decompress them first before you can load them if you want to manually download them. 7zip on windows is a good tool for this

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. I think the duckdb.install_extension API expects unzip software and since my windows native extractor doesn't supports it, the duckdb.install_extension quietly just copied the httpfs.duckdb_extension file to path  C:\Users\xxxx\.duckdb\extensions\v0.9.2\windows_amd64\  without highlighting that it couldn't uncompress the extension.